# Netgear wifi extender (Ac1200,Ex6110) unable to connect in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: command-line

I am trying to connect Netgear wifi extender (EX6110) TO MY PC running of ubuntu 22.04 but not connecting however my pc connecting another wifi very well.

Comment: Welcome to AU. Please [edit] the question and define/explain "not working". Typically with an extender one would connect to same SSID of the main router.

Comment: Not working means not connected to extender's network.however my pc connecting main router's  network but through extender it is not connecting.my mobile and windows pc is connecting to extender's network

Answer (score 0):

I have the very same problem. No solution. The SSID for the extender is simply not visible. And when I try to connect to it as a hidden network the connection fails. Works perfectly under Windows but not under Ubuntu. Are you using FastLane? That is the source of my problems.